# Regex input 1 ,2 ,3 into list

Tags: python, regex

Hello guys I'm trying to split this string

```
"1, 2, 3 , 4 , 5, 6,7"
```

into this array

```
['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
```

And get an error if there are characters or multiple spaces (one white space is acceptable following or before a comma)

I'm doing

```
re.split(r'\s?,\s?', some_string)
```

but this does not return an error for invalid matches such as (",," or ", ,"). How could I accomplish that ?

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'\d+', s)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a regex for this

```
>>> s = "1, 2, 3 , 4 , 5, 6,7"
>>> [i.strip() for i in s.split(',')]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

Comment: But that leaves the spaces near the commas if they exist